# How to stop VLC from blanking screens when in full screen mode?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player, fullscreen

I'm on a Mac OS X multi display setup watching movies using VLC. Whenever I enter full screen mode, the  other monitors fade to black. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a setting in VLC's preferences on macOS. Under the "Video" preferences tab, simply uncheck "**Black screens in Fullscreen mode**". You can also select a specific screen for fullscreen output from the "Fullscreen Video Device" dropdown.