# Stop other monitors from going black when in full screen mode on a Mac

Tags: display, osx-mountain-lion

How can I disable the blacking out of my second and third monitors when I play a movie in full screen mode?

Comment: What app are you using to watch your movie? I seem to recall VLC can be configured to not turn off full screen blanking: http://superuser.com/questions/296178/how-to-stop-vlc-from-blanking-screens-when-in-full-screen-mode?rq=1

Comment: I am using the QuickTime player, I would prefer to continue using QuickTime, but if the only way is to switch apps, then thats what I will do, now that you mentioned preferences, I will check the QuickTime preferences now

Comment: Nothing in the QuickTime preferences =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you're using the native full screen functionality of OS X there is no way to escape the hated linen background. I don't know why they force it on us but, as booyaa suggested above, you should be able to get the experience you want by using VLC.